# Login to amazon using BeautifulSoup leads to a "Unusual sign-in attempt detected"

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request

I have this code :

```
'''load packages'''
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


'''define URL where login form is located'''
site = 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/sign-in.html'

'''initiate session'''
session = requests.Session()

'''define session headers'''
session.headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Referer': site
}

'''get login page'''
resp = session.get(site)
html = resp.text

'''get BeautifulSoup object of the html of the login page'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

'''scrape login page to get all the needed inputs required for login'''
data = {}
form = soup.find('form', {'name': 'signIn'})
for field in form.find_all('input'):
    try:
        data[field['name']] = field['value']

    except:
        pass

'''add username and password to the data for post request'''
data[u'email'] = "test@gmail.com"
data[u'password'] = "albi"

'''submit post request with username / password and other needed info'''
post_resp = session.post('https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin', data=data)

post_soup = BeautifulSoup(post_resp.content, 'lxml')
with open('file2.html', "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(post_soup.decode("utf-8"))
    f.close()

if post_soup.find_all('title')[0].text == 'Your Account':
    print('Login Successfull')
else:
    print('Login Failed')
```

And this code leads me to this screen :
[image]

And I have to approve the connection on my phone... I receive a text message "From Amazon: Unusual sign-in attempt detected from XX, XX. View details here : ..."

I checked twice the ua, which is okay for basic requests like getting price or so.
Where should I take a look ?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this and the subsequent email this evening and unable to log into my account.  I am using a device and location that I have used frequently to log into my account and am not confident following the email instructions?!

Answer (score 0):

Genuine - I confirmed the issue with amazon this morning on my account that randomly started last night